# CSS Drop down menu hidden by photo

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, z-index

[link text](http://autoglass-plus.com/dev/)

The above link is a test site. The button titled "services" in the top navbar seems to be hidden in IE and not Firefox. Anyone else seeing it hidden behind the photo?

Thanks!

Comment: you have no styles for #navbar li ul li

Comment: and btw. your pictures are quite large, it takes too long to load the page.

Comment: I was wondering... I will optimize the photos again. Thanks for the note on the navbar lack of styling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try assigning z-index: 1000; to CSS style of the popup div.

Comment: I think that was it, thanks. I don't know why I didn't think of z-index. i wonder why IE is so much different than other browsers?